# Kyoukai no Rinne background music

Tags: music, kyoukai-no-rinne

I'm searching for the music of an anime.

The anime is "Kyoukai no Rinne".

The background music comes from episode 1 from 12:15 to 12:32.

Comment: Welcome to the Anime and Manga SE. What exactly are you trying to ask here?

Comment: I assume that you're looking for the title of the background music?

Comment: The soundtrack for Kyoukai no Rinne isn't even scheduled for release yet. Try again in a few months.

Answer (score 2):

It's Track 02 *Ningen... Mitai na ~Rinne no Theme* from the [Kyoukai no RINNE original sound track](http://vgmdb.net/album/53352).